# Magento 2 Ebizmarts Mailchimp extension error

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I installed ebizmarts mailchimp extension to my magento 2 store. 
After selecting the Apikey in stores tab, its not showing mailchimp list on the dropdown.

I am getting js error:

```
script error for: configmonkeyapikey
```

anyone else got the same issue and have solution for this?

thanks

Comment: I can see people voted to put this on hold as its a third-party module. I think its wrong as i searched for the answer and its a free module, and there are many users like me which will come to this issue and will want to find a fix.

Comment: Pablo here, from the Ebizmarts team.
Please contact our support at mailchimp@ebizmarts-desk.zendesk.com specifying the version you have installed and adding screenshots with your current configuration.
That way we may be able to replicate this and help you finding a definitive solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit i found a soution to this, which might not be the ideal solution but it works.

open **requirejs-config.js** file by going to **Ebizmarts/MailChimp/view/adminhtml** folder.

Find **configapikey** and replace it with **apikey**.

Refresh mailchimp configuration page, and again select the Apikey. It will call ajax and will populate data on that List dropdown.

After saving the form update the **requirejs-config.js** back to as it was before.